# How to get such a format - type map

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get this effect after clicking the save button
for example:

```
"timeTable":{
    "0": [{"from":"08:00","to":"12:00"}, {"from":"14:00","to":"18:20"}],
    "1": [{"from":"08:00","to":"16:00"}]
.....
  }
```

Unfortunately, I can not do this, please help. The result is:
for example:

```
{"0":{
   "0":{"from":"00:00","to":"23:00"}},
    "1":{"0":{"from":"08:00","to":"16:00"}}}
}
```

I don't know how to rewrite the getTimeline function...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-slrmqc?fbclid=IwAR3mZbHjz8TkLUZJI1kd7gsMnaPikdS0eyGzdF17RPYJ70jyHhXMOzW8x3w&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

interface Row {
  name: string;
  items: number[];
  active: boolean;
  day: number;
}
interface HourScheduleDefinitionModel {
  from: string;
  to: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  arr: Row[] = [
    { name: 'Monday', day: 0, items: new Array(24).fill(1), active: true },
    { name: 'Tuesday', day: 1, items: new Array(24).fill(0), active: false },
    {
      name: 'Wednesday',
      day: 2,
      items: new Array(24).fill(0),
      active: false,
    },
    { name: 'Thursday', day: 3, items: new Array(24).fill(0), active: false },
    { name: 'Friday', day: 4, items: new Array(24).fill(0), active: false },
    { name: 'Saturday', day: 5, items: new Array(24).fill(0), active: false },
    { name: 'Sunday', day: 6, items: new Array(24).fill(0), active: false },
  ];
  timeTable2: Map<number, Array<HourScheduleDefinitionModel>>;
  timeTable: HourScheduleDefinitionModel[][];

  // for example
  // "timeTable":{
  //   "0": [{"from":"08:00","to":"12:00"}, {"from":"14:00","to":"18:00"}],
  //   "1": [{"from":"08:00","to":"16:00"}]
  // }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.arr.forEach((row: Row, index: number) => {
      if (this.arr[index].items.every((col) => col === 1)) {
        row.active = true;
      }
    });
  }

  click(day: number, range: number) {
    this.arr[day].items[range] = this.arr[day].items[range] === 1 ? 0 : 1;
    this.arr[day].active = this.arr[day].items.every((col) => col === 1);
  }

  toggleRow(day: number): void {
    this.arr[day].items.fill(this.arr[day].active ? 0 : 1);
    this.arr[day].active = !this.arr[day].active;
  }

  getTimeline = () => {
    const result = [];
    console.log(this.arr);
    for (const item of this.arr) {
      let start = -1,
        timeTable = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < item.items.length; i++) {
        if (item.items[i] === 1) {
          if (start === -1) {
            start = i;
          }
        } else {
          if (start !== -1) {
            timeTable.push({
              from: start < 10 ? '0' + start + ':00' : start + ':00',
              to: i < 10 ? '0' + (i - 1) + ':00' : i - 1 + ':00',
            });
            start = -1;
          }
        }
        if (start !== -1 && i === item.items.length - 1) {
          timeTable.push({
            from: start < 10 ? '0' + start + ':00' : start + ':00',
            to: '23:00',
          });
        }
      }
      // if(timeTable.length){
      result.push({
        // day: item.day,
        ...timeTable,
      });
      // }
    }
    return result;
  };

  save() {
    this.timeTable = this.getTimeline();
    console.log(this.timeTable);
    let val = { ...this.timeTable };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(val));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
// The Row interface as you defined it
interface Row {
    name: string;
    items: number[];
    active: boolean;
    day: number;
}

// The dummy data you provided
const arr: Row[] = [
    { name: 'Monday', day: 0, items: new Array(24).fill(1), active: true },
    { name: 'Tuesday', day: 1, items: new Array(24).fill(0), active: false },
    { name: 'Wednesday', day: 2, items: new Array(24).fill(0), active: false },
    { name: 'Thursday', day: 3, items: new Array(24).fill(0), active: false },
    { name: 'Friday', day: 4, items: new Array(24).fill(0), active: false },
    { name: 'Saturday', day: 5, items: new Array(24).fill(0), active: false },
    { name: 'Sunday', day: 6, items: new Array(24).fill(0), active: false },
];

// An interface to describe the concept of a period (e.g. {"from":"08:00","to":"12:00"})
interface Period {
    from: string;
    to: string;
}

// A function to convert an array of 24 numbers into an array of Periods
const getPeriodsForDay = (items: number[]): Period[] => {
    const result: Period[] = [];
    let i = 0;
    let periodStartIndex: number | null = null;
    let isCurrentIndexActive = false;

    while (i < items.length) {
        isCurrentIndexActive = items[i] === 1;
        if (isCurrentIndexActive && periodStartIndex == null)
        {
            periodStartIndex = i;
        } else if (!isCurrentIndexActive && periodStartIndex != null) {
             result.push({ from: convertToTimeString(periodStartIndex), to: convertToTimeString(i) });
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (isCurrentIndexActive && periodStartIndex != null) {
        result.push({ from: convertToTimeString(periodStartIndex), to: convertToTimeString(i - 1) });
    }
    return result;
}

// Utility function to transform an index into your desired string (e.g. 3 would become "03:00")
const convertToTimeString = (index: number) => {
    return `${index.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:00`
};

// A function to create the wrapper around the result
const getTimeTable = (rows: Row[]) => {
    const timeTable: { [key: string]: Period[] } = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        timeTable[i] = getPeriodsForDay(rows[i].items);
    }

    return {
        timeTable: timeTable
    }
};

console.log(getTimeTable(arr));
```

See [Typescript Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsDuyDeBYAKGWORDgFsIAuZAZzClAHMBuQk5YSc2mkAV3IAjaAG0AumyIlEYYADdqyIenQAbCHBBSOAEzgBPPoJFQpAX0KEE6EPWRwoUGhkwTkAXmSj2JHKQolAHIAWVt9AyCAGmQImgAGGK4IHj4IbABBJ0MACgAmABYASgA6GGA1NRyARiKY2QUlBn4UcyjfYn8yShoggBUW2gjo2MMaaqTuXlJ05CyoXMLS8sqc+LqHBDlFGng1Wlb26U6AnuQggHUIXRAIIcMRuOQ8yZTp28zsg3zisoqq9b1LaNXZwfaHDq4U7BPoAC34UHukRiTwAzK9UjNPgtvks-qtAZttko9gdkG1IV1Ar0AGKMYYosbIAoY96zeaLX4rAEbBo7ZCkiHHKHdYIAZTgYARDNGRmQAFZWWlsZzlv81rzgfzBeSjhwqWcgmL+CAZU8AGxKrFzL4-NUEzXE0Hg3WESRWAigSCwRAoAAK0GA6F0uEhMCg6HINHojBArEhYHQ0YYzAsHpsdjAyCYEDAAcYwdoNPQUAAIoZPMgcslMQJhGJxEUaPmg7p3B4AHyh4UZ+xQO78NRgZuB4Pt7zu4UaLPASvxHQkafIAAOo90YrAjjAAElTRAAB7GetQZAAH1Ig7UlYElQXxCXwFoAGEEf3wLvdAeMlqUF5BVJIUwWEKhQatkAAHk4KYSg0OMwFhIpuw4DhHxfJwIHfPd92-YlKxrWhRGAcRPA8LxqjvZDgBgKtUNfDCdywnDGmQAAyFiVzXDctw-A8SIvSoikhfUhOQ4hVwLddNygBjP33PCKI4cxkAgF0qKrABCWj0Mw2SmMUVj2PE1suOkni5PUrwbzURD8GFUSSH7WhBzAEpl34WhYRyfxw0jGgM0UaS+nQPpgEoDdYyYHIjODEyZIPDZEz82wArAIKQrClM42rRDzCKBSSEsOySGAABqEqKMKyE1OrZ86J0r8fwMjiJNiszkAs-jrKQ+zHOc1z3M87yIyjZB-OgVLgtCiBwuYKLOKkuL9wSpNRuS8a0qmmastnABaZBanJPLIUKjh+ylKAQGQXqhzTAhrFsewxsCyaMoiytqywo9TEQztuuIM6EUugADAASHBQFkkpEy2yLSmXOBJK3fIYgAIniFGinMKh4niIHCHMACCF7LMc1Sqa+jgIQNHeiNMGmVwJB+rtbI4YnkDkSgKappR-FEABrCA5RjZhxBHCT3CUrwcAJsMSxyB85xYTgIKurBaBgjCmHgpXSpKmyROIDmIC5jRCOIrxSZbQtizLXJaYIoiSnwo7hUq4UAYuv7kKNk2mnJymNGO-HCd7dQIBg9BItJ9LjYDiAckcKAijyoA)